# Given a Facebook username, how do I get the ID of the profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want the ID, not the username.  But given the username...what do I have to do?

Comment: how are you getting the user name? Which language do you wish to achieve this in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/username

e.g.

https://graph.facebook.com/boxoft

{
   "id": "1264933131",
   "name": "Box He",
   "first_name": "Box",
   "last_name": "He",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/boxoft",
   "username": "boxoft",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}

Comment: Amazing. No need to use the complex OAuth.

Comment: I'm currently getting a "*(#803) Cannot query users by their username (usernamehere)*" error message when trying this method.

Comment: This api is deprecated

Comment: This no longer works without a proper Oauth token (public calls depreciated)

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to get an exact match but will get some results. Via Gra[ph Api docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Owalla&type=user
```